# How to wait for an asio handler?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, synchronous, c++03

I have an object that runs around a `boost::asio::io_service` which has some properties. Something like that:

```
class Foo
{
  private:

    // Not an int in my real code, but it doesn't really matter.
    int m_bar;
    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
    boost::asio::strand m_bar_strand;
};
```

`m_bar` is to be used only from a handler that is called through the strand `m_bar_strand`. This allows me not to lock from within those handlers.

To set the `m_bar` property from outside a thread that runs `io_service::run()` I wrote an asynchronous_setter, like so:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    void async_get_bar(function<void (int)> handler)
    {
      m_bar_strand.post(bind(&Foo::do_get_bar, this, handler));
    }

    void async_set_bar(int value, function<void ()> handler)
    {
      m_bar_strand.post(bind(&Foo::do_set_bar, this, value, handler));
    }

  private:

    void do_get_bar(function<void (int)> handler)
    {
      // This is only called from within the m_bar_strand, so we are safe.

      // Run the handler to notify the caller.
      handler(m_bar);
    }

    void do_set_bar(int value, function<void ()> handler)
    {
      // This is only called from within the m_bar_strand, so we are safe.
      m_bar = value;

      // Run the handler to notify the caller.
      handler();
    }

    int m_bar;
    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
    boost::asio::strand m_bar_strand;
};
```

This works perfectly but now I'd like to write a synchronous version of `set_bar` that sets the value  and returns only when the set was effective. It must still guarantee that the effective set will occur within the `m_bar_strand`. Ideally, something reentrant.

I can imagine solutions with semaphores that would be modified from within the handler but everything I come up seems hackish and really not elegant. Is there something in Boost/Boost Asio that allows such a thing?

How would you proceed to implement this method?

Comment: void sync_set_bar(int value, function<void()>handler) { m_bar = value; handler();} And go ahead an make m_bar boost::atomic<int>.

Comment: (though I'm not sure what synchronization controls you need on m_bar, so I may be just screwing you up) No need to use asio when things aren't async.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: The `m_bar` value (whatever its type) should only be changed (or accessed) from **within** a handler that runs inside the `m_bar_strand`. This prevents race conditions without using mutexes and is kind of nice. I just want to turn an asynchronous call into a synchronous one.

Comment: This also ensures that m_bar can only be accessed from m_bar_strand, but I can work with that. c++11?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Yep exactly. Sadly, C++03 or I would have used a lambda handler already :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to synchronously wait on a value to be set, then  Boost.Thread's [`futures`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) may provide an elegant solution:

> The futures library provides a means of handling synchronous future values, whether those values are generated by another thread, or on a single thread in response to external stimuli, or on-demand.

In short, a [`boost::promise`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.promise) is created and allows for a value to be set on it.  The value can later be retrieved via an associated [`boost::future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future).  Here is a basic example:

```cpp
boost::promise<int> promise;
boost::unique_future<int> future = promise.get_future();

// start asynchronous operation that will invoke future.set_value(42)
...

assert(future.get() == 42); // blocks until future has been set.
```

Two other notable benefits to this approach:

- `future` is part of C++11.
- Exceptions can even be passed to `future` via [`promise::set_exception()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.promise.set_exception), supporting an elegant way to provide exceptions or errors to the caller.

---

Here is a complete example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:

  Foo(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : m_io_service(io_service),
      m_bar_strand(io_service)
  {}

public:

  void async_get_bar(boost::function<void(int)> handler)
  {
    m_bar_strand.post(bind(&Foo::do_get_bar, this, handler));
  }

  void async_set_bar(int value, boost::function<void()> handler)
  {
    m_bar_strand.post(bind(&Foo::do_set_bar, this, value, handler));
  }

  int bar()
  {
    typedef boost::promise<int> promise_type;
    promise_type promise;

    // Pass the handler to async operation that will set the promise.
    void (promise_type::*setter)(const int&) = &promise_type::set_value;
    async_get_bar(boost::bind(setter, &promise, _1));

    // Synchronously wait for promise to be fulfilled.
    return promise.get_future().get();
  }

  void bar(int value)
  {
    typedef boost::promise<void> promise_type;
    promise_type promise;

    // Pass the handler to async operation that will set the promise.
    async_set_bar(value, boost::bind(&promise_type::set_value, &promise));

    // Synchronously wait for the future to finish.
    promise.get_future().wait();
  }

private:

  void do_get_bar(boost::function<void(int)> handler)
  {
    // This is only called from within the m_bar_strand, so we are safe.

    // Run the handler to notify the caller.
    handler(m_bar);
  }

  void do_set_bar(int value, boost::function<void()> handler)
  {
    // This is only called from within the m_bar_strand, so we are safe.
    m_bar = value;

    // Run the handler to notify the caller.
    handler();
  }

  int m_bar;
  boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
  boost::asio::strand m_bar_strand;
};

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
  boost::thread t(
      boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, boost::ref(io_service)));

  Foo foo(io_service);
  foo.bar(21);
  std::cout << "foo.bar is " << foo.bar() << std::endl;
  foo.bar(2 * foo.bar());
  std::cout << "foo.bar is " << foo.bar() << std::endl;

  io_service.stop();
  t.join();
}
```

which provides the following output:

```
foo.bar is 21
foo.bar is 42
```

Comment: I haven't thought of `future`: could very well be a nicer solution ! However doesn't this code create a thread to wait for the future ?

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't... which makes sense when you think about it. Thanks for the trick ! Definitely better style than my own made up solution. Perhaps it would just be worth mentioning that calling set a setter/getter from **inside** a handler can deadlock (if the called handler is run inside the same thread than the calling handler).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pipe to notify the synchronous method when the value is set in `async_set_bar()`. Warning, the below code is brain-compiled and likely has errors but it should get the point across

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>                                                                                                                       

class Foo                                                                                                                               
{
public:                                                                                                                                 
    Foo( boost::asio::io_service& io_service ) :                                                                                        
        _bar( 0 ),
        _io_service( io_service ),                                                                                                      
        _strand( _io_service ),                                                                                                         
        _readPipe( _io_service ),
        _writePipe( _io_service )
    {
        boost::asio::local::connect_pair( _readPipe, _writePipe );
    }

    void set_async( int v ) {
        _strand.post( [=]
            {
                _bar = v;
                std::cout << "sending " << _bar << std::endl; 
                _writePipe.send( boost::asio::buffer( &_bar, sizeof(_bar) ) );
            }
            );
    }

    void set_sync( int v ) {
        this->set_async( v );
        int value;
        _readPipe.receive( boost::asio::buffer(&value, sizeof(value) ) );
        std::cout << "set value to " << value << std::endl;
    }


private:
    int _bar;
    boost::asio::io_service& _io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::strand _strand;
    boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket _readPipe;
    boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket _writePipe;
};

int
main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work w(io_service);
    std::thread t( [&]{ io_service.run(); } );
    Foo f( io_service );
    f.set_sync( 20 );
    io_service.stop();
    t.join();
}
```

if you are unable to use c++11 lambdas, replace them with `boost::bind` and some more completion handler methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
class synchronizer_base
{
    protected:
        synchronizer_base() :
            m_has_result(false),
            m_lock(m_mutex)
        {
        }

        void wait()
        {
            while (!m_has_result)
            {
                m_condition.wait(m_lock);
            }
        }

        void notify_result()
        {
            m_has_result = true;
            m_condition.notify_all();
        }

    private:

        boost::atomic<bool> m_has_result;
        boost::mutex m_mutex;
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> m_lock;
        boost::condition_variable m_condition;
};

template <typename ResultType = void>
class synchronizer : public synchronizer_base
{
    public:

        void operator()(const ResultType& result)
        {
            m_result = result;

            notify_result();
        }

        ResultType wait_result()
        {
            wait();

            return m_result;
        }

    private:

        ResultType m_result;
};

template <>
class synchronizer<void> : public synchronizer_base
{
    public:

        void operator()()
        {
            notify_result();
        }

        void wait_result()
        {
            wait();
        }
};
```

And I can use it, that way:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    void async_get_bar(function<void (int)> handler)
    {
      m_bar_strand.post(bind(&Foo::do_get_bar, this, value, handler));
    }

    void async_set_bar(int value, function<void ()> handler)
    {
      m_bar_strand.post(bind(&Foo::do_set_bar, this, value, handler));
    }

    int get_bar()
    {
      synchronizer<int> sync;

      async_get_bar(boost::ref(sync));

      return sync.wait_result();
    }

    void set_bar(int value)
    {
      synchronizer<void> sync;

      async_set_bar(value, boost::ref(sync));

      sync.wait_result();
    }
};
```

The `boost::ref` is necessary because the instances of `synchronizer` are non-copyable. This could be avoided by wrapping `synchronizer` in some other container-class, but I'm fine with that solution as it is.

*Note: Do **NOT** call such "synchronized" functions from inside a handler or it might just deadlock !*